# Access parent element from different component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a button component that is passed in my main app.js component and I need to change the style of the parent element of the button. Apparently parentNode is not following reacts rules, so how can I change the buttons parentNode classes style in the react way? There are multiple "student-container". How can I display: block on only the parent element of the button selected?

App.js

```
import Button from "./components/Button";

function App() {

 {student
        .filter(
          (name) =>
            name.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(studentFilter) ||
            name.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(studentFilter)
        )
        .map((students) => {
          

          return (
            <div key={students.id} className="student-container">
              <img alt="students" className="student-img" src={students.pic} />
              <div className="student-column">
                <p className="student-item">
                  {" "}
                  {students.firstName} {students.lastName}
                </p>
              

                <div className="display-score-container">
                  {students.grades.map((test, index) => {
                    return (
                      <p key={index} className="student-score">
                        Test {index + 1}:{" "}
                        <span className="student-percentage">{test}%</span>
                      </p>
                    );
                  })}

                  
                </div>
              </div>

              <Button></Button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
}
```

Button.js

```
export default function Button() {
  const [buttonLabel, setButtonLabel] = useState("+");

  const toggleButtonLabel = (e) => {
    setButtonLabel(buttonLabel === "+" ? "-" : "+");

//e.target.parentNode.style.display = "block"//
   
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggleButtonLabel} className="expand-btn">
        {buttonLabel}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My thought is to include the return value of the array mapping into the Button component. Then use ternary to check if the specific button is selected, add `className` props to that exact component. I use [spread syntax for props](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes).

If the condition is true, it spread object `{className: 'student-container'}` as props, but if the condition is false, it spread empty object `{}`, which means no props added.

App.js

```js
import Button from "./components/Button";

function App() {
  return (
  <SomeParentComponents>
    <SomeOtherParentComponents>
      {student
         .filter(
           (name) =>
             name.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(studentFilter) ||
             name.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(studentFilter)
         )
         .map((studentItem) => <Button studentItem={studentItem} />)}
    </SomeOtherParentComponents>
  </SomeParentComponents>
}
```

Button.js

```js
export default function Button(props) {
  const {studentItem} = props;
  const [buttonLabel, setButtonLabel] = useState("+");

  const toggleButtonLabel = () => {
    setButtonLabel(buttonLabel === "+" ? "-" : "+");
  };

  return (
    <div key={studentItem.id} ...(buttonLabel === '+' ? {className: 'student-container'} : {})>
      <img alt="students" className="student-img" src={studentItem.pic} />
      <div className="student-column">
        <p className="student-item">
          {` ${studentItem.firstName} ${studentItem.lastName}`}
        </p>
      
        <div className="display-score-container">
          {studentItem.grades.map((test, index) => {
            return (
              <p key={index} className="student-score">
                {`Test ${index + 1}: `}
                <span className="student-percentage">{`${test}%`}</span>
              </p>
            );
          })}
          
        </div>
      </div>

      <button onClick={toggleButtonLabel} className="expand-btn">
        {buttonLabel}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

That is the beauty of React Component, right. You may add and combine multiple basic html component into personalized component and tweak its stylings or states.

P.S. I use some personal preferences on code style for the example:

- prefer use [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with backtick and `${variableName}`
- have some liberty renaming variable name (bold and sometime offensive move!), which of course you can rename based on your personal likings or coding style standard